# How does a local resource file look like?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I can't seem to find a detailed example of how a local resource file looks like and its content

I have been reading up on this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx

I want to use implicit localization with local resources.

So if I have a page: Products.aspx and want to create a default resource file then I need to create Products.aspx.resx and placed in App_LocalResources folder?

What does it contain say for example I want to change the values for a button control with `ID="btnSubmit"` ?

Is it like:

`btnSubmit.Text = "Click here"`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would place the "Products.aspx.resx" in the App_LocalResources.

You would then create an item in the resource file where:

Name = btnSubmit.text

Value = Click Here

your aspx page would have the button with the resource key defined:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" meta:resourcekey="btnSubmit"   />
```

Comment: so I only need to put in the btnSubmit.Text resource file the text **Click Here** ?

Comment: Yes, the resource file contains a list of name - value pairs.